# Can we crawl and index Google Drive documents using nutch and solr?

Tags: solr, google-drive-api, nutch, moss2007enterprisesearch

I have tried indexing public url of a google drive document, but it seems that it does not work . Is there any way to crawl google drive documents via nutch and make their index using solr?

Answer (score 2):

Use Google Drive API to read/manage files

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

Drive Public URL's page won't have direct links to subdirectories, so you will get nothing if you crawl those pages.